# $R$ Noetherian, $M$ finitely generated module. If $P$ is minimal over $\operatorname{ann}M$, how is $M' = \ker (M \to M_P)$ a $P$-primary submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, modules

Let $R$ be Noetherian and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module.

We know a theorem which says: $M$ is $P$-coprimary iff $P$ is minimal over $\operatorname{ann}M$ and $M$ injects into $M_P$.

Now the claim is:

> If $M$ is any finitely generated $R$-module and $P$ is minimal over the annihilator of $M$, then the submodule $M' \subset M$ defined by $M' = \ker (M \to M_P)$ is $P$-primary because $M/M'$ injects into $(M/M')_P \cong M_P$.

---

**Why is this true? Is $P$ minimal over $\operatorname{ann}(M/M')$?**

Answer (score 1):

First note that, if $P$ is minimal over $ann M$, then $Ass(M_P)=\{P\}$.

Now $M/M'\hookrightarrow M_P$, hence $Ass(M/M')\subset Ass(M_P)=\{P\}$. But $M/M'$ is a non-zero module, so $Ass(M/M')=\{P\}$. Thus $M'$ is $P$-primary.