# How to show that ${\rm Ass}(M_{\mathfrak p})=\{\mathfrak p\}$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, localization, noetherian

[$R$ Noetherian, $M$ finitely generated module. If $P$ is minimal over $\operatorname{ann}M$, how is $M' = \ker (M \to M_P)$ a $P$-primary submodule?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3940814/r-noetherian-m-finitely-generated-module-if-p-is-minimal-over-operator)

While using this question and answer to solve my question, I found that I need to show that ${\rm Ass}(M_{\mathfrak p})=\{\mathfrak p\}$. Can someone help me to show that ${\rm Ass}(M_{\mathfrak p})=\{\mathfrak p\}$?

Comment: There are two facts: 1/ any associated prime of $M$ contains $ann(M)$. 2/ Any associated prime of $M_P$ is contained in $P$.